# Social security treaty/convention between Germany and Israel - German text?

Tags: germany, legal, social-security, israel

Israel and Germany have a treaty (or a convention if you will) regarding social security benefits: Unemployment, accidents, old-age, disability etc.

The Hebrew version of the convention can be downloaded from [here](https://www.btl.gov.il/Laws1/10_0011_000000.pdf) (btl.gov.il - the Israeli national insurance website; may require login) or [here](https://app.box.com/s/vlltgppxs444b5wj31exbo3z7z3nwxn1) (a copy I made on Box.com). But - I couldn't find the German version of the convention; and I need it for an acquaintance of mine who doesn't speak Hebrew.

Comment: Your link does not work (maybe a login required?). Can you supply the german name of the agreement? The pdf that can be downloaded here: [DRV - Homepage - Arbeiten in Deutschland und in Israel](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Broschueren/international/weitere_abkommen/25_arbeiten_deutschland_israel.html;jsessionid=9313E9AE4ED708B3BFE617D387CD01B9.delivery1-7-replication) meantions that the 1975 agreement text is contained in a pamphlet that is available against a fee.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Fixed the link, or rather added another one. I don't have the German name. The full Hebrew name (translated) is  "Treaty between the state of Israel and the Federal Republic of Germany Regarding Social Security". It has two date: Publication date Oct 5th 1975, Date of copy Nov 20th 1978. Not sure how those two make sense.